# Centered vertical dots inside pmatrix don't show when using `unicode-math`

Tags: xetex, matrices, unicode-math

I'm trying to use centered vertical dots in a `pmatrix`, as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366316/30481). However, when `unicode-math` is used, the `\vdots` don't appear inside a `pmatrix`, although they appear just fine in other cases. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
% \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
% \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[Scale = 1.0]

\begin{document}

$a\vdots b$
$\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b\vdots \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{2$\vdots$} \\ 
    a & b
\end{pmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

This compiles to

[image]

in which the `\vdots`  next to the `2` are clearly missing.
Commenting out the `\usepackage{unicode-math}`, the `vdots` show up where they should.

I need to use `unicode-math` as I'm using XeLaTeX (or do I?), so how can I work around this problem?

Comment: $\vdots$  would be an error with or without unicode-math, remove the `$` you are already in math mode

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, that was easy, thanks. They used the math environment in the linked answer and I didn't think that that could have been the problem here (especially because removing the unicode-math package it worked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/514394/centered-vertical-dots-inside-pmatrix-dont-show-when-using-unicode-math?noredirect=1#comment1300808_514394), I just needed to remove the `$$` wrapping the `\vdots` in the `pmatrix`, which was wrong in the first place as I was already in math mode.

I foolishly copied the command with the `$$` from the linked answer, where I guess it was just used by mistake.